# java InputMismatchException reading from a file

Tags: java, input, file-io, decision-tree

I'm implementing a driver program to test a decision tree and I'm getting an input mismatch exception. What can I do to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * LoanApprovalAnaylyzer demonstrates the use of a binary decision tree to 
 * decide the approval of a loan.
 */
public class LoanApprovalAnalyzer
{
    /**
     *  Asks questions of the user to get their credit worthiness.
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        System.out.println ("So, you need a loan.");

        DecisionTree expert = new DecisionTree("input2.txt");
        expert.evaluate();
    }
}
```

This is what my input file has:

```
13
Is your income above $100,000?
Do you have more than 3 dependants?
Do you have more than 6 dependants?
Do you own real estate worth less than $200,000?
Do you own real estate worth more than $200,000?
Are you above the age of 60?
Are you above the age of 45?
Your loan is not approved.
Your loan is approved.
Your loan is not approved.
Your loan is approved
Your loan is not approved.
Your loan is approved
Your loan is not approved.
Your loan is approved
3 7 8
4 9 10
5 11 12
1 3 4
2 5 6
0 1 2
```

This is my decision tree code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * The DecisionTree class uses the LinkedBinaryTree class to implement 
 * a binary decision tree. Tree elements are read from a given file and  
 * then the decision tree can be evaluated based on user input using the
 * evaluate method. 
 * 
 * @author Java Foundations
 * @version 4.0
 */
public class DecisionTree
{
    private LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree;

    /**
     * Builds the decision tree based on the contents of the given file
     *
     * @param filename the name of the input file
     * @throws FileNotFoundException if the input file is not found
     */
    public DecisionTree(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        int numberNodes = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        int root = 0, left, right;

        List<LinkedBinaryTree<String>> nodes = new java.util.ArrayList<LinkedBinaryTree<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++)
            nodes.add(i,new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(scan.nextLine()));

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            root = scan.nextInt();
            left = scan.nextInt();
            right = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            nodes.set(root, new LinkedBinaryTree<String>((nodes.get(root)).getRootElement(), 
                                                       nodes.get(left), nodes.get(right)));
        }
        tree = nodes.get(root);
    }

    /**
     *  Follows the decision tree based on user responses.
     */
    public void evaluate()
    {
        LinkedBinaryTree<String> current = tree;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (current.size() > 1)
        {
            System.out.println (current.getRootElement());
            if (scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                current = current.getLeft();
            else
                current = current.getRight();
        }

        System.out.println (current.getRootElement());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is DecisionTree? Post its code.

Comment: @DeepeshChoudhary done

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

In your input file, the first number is 13, so your code skips 13 lines and EXPECTS and integer in the next line(`nextInt()`). But there are 15 lines to be skipped so that you can get an integer in the next line.

Solution: In the input file, change 13 to 15 in the first line.

Comment: just one more problem. in my decision tree, when I get to the point "Are you above the age of 45?" it doesn't allow me to give the next input to get to the last node. But all the other paths are working. what went wrong here

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't allow me*?

Comment: meaning once I get to that question, i enter the next input on the keyboard and it is not recognizing the next input from the keyboard

Comment: It is not recognising your input, so what is the expected output and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: basically what i am saying is, the i/o goes like this: it asks a question, i type, yes, asks another question, i type yes, asks another question, here i need to be able to type y/n but it is not letting me type that – so i don't even get an output at that step

Comment: Try changing `3 7 8` to `3 7 7` in your input file, and tell whether it works or not.

Comment: this is what it looks like when i run the program: http://imgur.com/a/BfaS0

Comment: after it says "are you above the age of 45?" i cannot enter anything in

Comment: Change `while (current.size() > 1)` to `while (current.size() > 0)`. And again tell me if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144138/discussion-between-johnny-sack-and-deepesh-choudhary).